# How to change Pytorch model to work with 3d input instead 2d input?

Tags: pytorch, reinforcement-learning, conv-neural-network, stable-baselines

I am trying to train an agent to play [Connect4](https://www.kaggle.com/c/connectx) game. I found an example of how it can be trained. Representation of board is 1x6x7 array:

```
[[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 0 2]
  [0 0 0 0 0 0 1]]]
```

This neural network architecture is used:

```
class Net(BaseFeaturesExtractor):
    def __init__(self, observation_space: gym.spaces.Box, features_dim: int = 256):
        super(Net, self).__init__(observation_space, features_dim)
        # We assume CxHxW images (channels first)
        # Re-ordering will be done by pre-preprocessing or wrapper
        n_input_channels = observation_space.shape[0]
        self.cnn = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(n_input_channels, 32, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(64, 128, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=0),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Flatten(),
        )

        # Compute shape by doing one forward pass
        with th.no_grad():
            n_flatten = self.cnn(th.as_tensor(observation_space.sample()[None]).float()).shape[1]

        self.linear = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(n_flatten, features_dim), nn.ReLU())

    def forward(self, observations: th.Tensor) -> th.Tensor:
        return self.linear(self.cnn(observations))
```

And it scored not so bad on a game with an agent 2 which moves randomly:

```
Agent 1 Win Percentage: 0.59 
Agent 2 Win Percentage: 0.38 
Number of Invalid Plays by Agent 1: 3 
Number of Invalid Plays by Agent 2: 0
Number of Draws (in 100 game rounds): 0
```

[Here](https://www.kaggle.com/c/connectx/discussion/168246) 3 layers representation was suggested as one of the ways how an agent can be improved:

[image]

I have tried to implement it and this is the example of the new 3 layer representation of board:

```
[[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 0 1]]

 [[0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 0 1]
  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]

 [[0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 0 1]
  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [1 1 1 1 1 1 0]]]
```

When I run this with the current neural network architecture, the agent is not able to train appropriately:

```
Agent 1 Win Percentage: 0.0
Agent 2 Win Percentage: 0.0
Number of Invalid Plays by Agent 1: 100
Number of Invalid Plays by Agent 2: 0
Number of Draws (in 100 game rounds): 0
```

[Here](https://github.com/VSZM/ConnectX/compare/master...JoeRakhimov:master) you can see my code.

As you can see now I have 3 layers instead of one. That's why I have tried to use Conv3d:

```
class Net(BaseFeaturesExtractor):
    def __init__(self, observation_space: gym.spaces.Box, features_dim: int = 256):
        super(Net, self).__init__(observation_space, features_dim)
        # We assume CxHxW images (channels first)
        # Re-ordering will be done by pre-preprocessing or wrapper
        n_input_channels = observation_space.shape[0]
        self.cnn = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv3d(n_input_channels, 32, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv3d(32, 64, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv3d(64, 128, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=0),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Flatten(),
        )

        # Compute shape by doing one forward pass
        with th.no_grad():
            n_flatten = self.cnn(th.as_tensor(observation_space.sample()[None]).float()).shape[1]

        self.linear = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(n_flatten, features_dim), nn.ReLU())
```

When I try to run this code, it is showing this error:

> RuntimeError: Expected 5-dimensional input for 5-dimensional weight
> [32, 1, 3, 3, 3], but got 4-dimensional input of size [1, 3, 6, 7]
> instead

My question: how can I use Conv3D layer with 3x6x7 shaped input?

Comment: I don't think you need conv3d here. It's still 2d with more input channels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment from Shai is correct. You do not need to use Conv3D layer here. The shape of your Conv3D filters would violate the calculation of size after application of a convolutional filter by reducing at least 1 dimension to less than 1 which is why you are getting your error (you can't multiple with a value that does not exist).

Simply using the original model implementation should work for you.

Similar to images with 3 color bands, these are typically not processed with Conv3d (maybe a different case with hyperspectral images, but that is not relevant here). There is some discussion about how to treat each of the color bands, and you can affect this in a variety of ways.

For example, adjusting the `groups` argument of the Conv2D layer at instantiation will change the connections between `in_channels` and `out_channels` of the layer and which are convolved to which, as per their documentation: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Conv2d.html.

You may be able to optimize this in your model, or otherwise experiment with it.

In any case, simply using the existing implementation with Conv2D should be fine for you. Conv3D is typically utilized in the case of 3 spatial dimensions, or sometimes 2 spatial and 1 temporal dimension. While your case is kind of like a limited version of 3 spacial dimensions, it is not necessarily the same as, say, a 3D vector-field of fluid flow in regards to how each "pixel" has some spatial relevance/correlation to its neighboring "pixels". Your "spatial pixels" have a somewhat different kind of relevance or correlation mapping than this.

Comment: Yes, I have tried to train the agent with conv2d however it is not able to train properly. Also, I should note that 3 layer input is a representation of a 6x7 board in the Connect4 game. The first layer is for the first player, the second layer is for the second player and the third layer shows possible moves for the player with the current moves.

Comment: Thanks for the information about what each board representation is from. By not being able to train properly, do you just mean that it does not converge or perform well? If so, you might try changing the `groups` argument to be equivalent to the `in_channels` argument, or by otherwise directly implementing separate conv layers to handle each of the board states (and later concatenating them) to ensure that the temporal disparity is separable and its relevance learnable by the model.

Comment: If you choose to do the latter mentioned in my last comment, I would change from using `self.cnn = nn.Sequential(...)` to

```
self.conv1_p1 = nn.Conv2d(...)
self.conv2_p1 = nn.Conv2d(...)

self.conv1_p2 = nn.Conv2d(...)

self.conv1_moves = nn.Conv2d(...)
```

etc. Essentially building multiple of the cnn's. You could also just use multiple `nn.Sequential` models and later concatenate their output in the `forward()` function.